# Taxonomist Badge - How can I earn this badge?

Tags: support, badges, tag-wiki, badge-progress

I am confused about the Taxonomist badge. Its tagline is **"Create a tag used by 50 questions"**. So my questions are:

1. I created a few tags by clicking the `help us create it` option. So I created those tags by adding excerpt and description. These tags had already been used by many questions, so does usage of this after tag creation count for the Taxonomist badge?
2. How can a person track his/her created tag usage count from his/her created date? When I see some of my created tags it will show the complete overall usage count. Is there any way to figure out the count of tag usage after my creation of the tag, not the overall usage count which includes usage of the tag before the creation?

For reference, please check the screenshot of how I created the tag by clicking "Help us create it":

[image]

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Comment: See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for#188732 for #1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think part of your confusion is that you're seeing two similar phrases but not considering their *antecedents*.

For the badge, you need to [create the **tag**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). The actual tag. If there's a tag already being used on the site, then the tag has already been created by someone else. The only way to get the badge is to find a subject that needs a tag that doesn't currently exist, create the tag ([reputation required varies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/284336)) from scratch and have it added to 50+ questions over time.

In your image, the antecedent is "usage guidance". Creating the usage guidance is not the same as creating the tag itself. While this information is very valuable and important to the site, it is not what gets the badge. If your tag wiki excerpt or tag wiki edit (creation) suggestion is accepted, you'll earn 2 reputation for that.

---

As a note, there are times when a tag was created on the site but later deleted. If you re-create that tag, the credit for creation goes to the person who created the tag originally.

Comment: So my question How do I create the tag? I have enough reputation to create the tag in Magento stack exchange site. I read some where during question when you add tags by writing keyword and tag not appear you have to just write the meaningful keyword and enter space bar, tag added to the question and also created as well, so is that way I create the tag?

Comment: Thanks @Catija marked your answer and voted as well. please add the creation part of the tag in the answer as well. So it helps other readers as well.

Comment: I've added a link to the tag creation privilege explanation, which tells you how and when to create tags.

Comment: Tag creation rep required is too complicated to explain in the paragraph. See the linked answer for more info.